# Problem with Jacob COM bridge when run as Windows service

Tags: java, outlook, com, mapi

i'm writing an app resposnible for downloading emails from an MAPI mailbox. MAPI is only avalaible protocol that i can use. So after research i found out that i'm forced to use a COM bridge to call Outlook methods because there is no other solutions for connecting java app to MAPI mailbox. I have made an simple test app that could save whole email as a .eml file. But there is a problem when i'm trying to run this app as Windows service, my app just hangs at executing `SaveAs` method of Outlook `MailItem` object. When i start this app as normal jar wverythings works fine, but when i run it as service on LocalSystem account using YAJSW it just stops executing at that method.

```
        ActiveXComponent outlook = new ActiveXComponent("Outlook.Application");
        Dispatch namespace = Dispatch.call(outlook ,"GetNamespace","MAPI").toDispatch();


        Dispatch sourceFolder = Dispatch.call(namespace,"GetDefaultFolder", 6).toDispatch(); //Folder with all emails to save ID:6
        Dispatch doneFolder = Dispatch.call(namespace,"GetDefaultFolder", 23).toDispatch(); //Folder with backups of done emails ID:23

        Dispatch mailList = Dispatch.get(sourceFolder, "Items").toDispatch();
        int itemCount = Dispatch.call(mailList, "Count").getInt();
        LOGGER.info("Mail count: " + itemCount);

        for(int i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
            Dispatch mail = Dispatch.call(mailList, "Item", i).toDispatch();
            LOGGER.info("Saving mail: " + tempMsgPath);
            Dispatch.call(mail, "SaveAs", tempMsgPath); //hangs there
            LOGGER.info("Mail saved");
            more code....
        }
```

I don't think this a problem with user privileges, tested that and thats not an issue. It must work as service, i know that there is a Outlook Redemption but i don't want to buy any lib. Maybe there is other way of geting mails from this mailbox over MAPI?

Comment: *"Maybe there is other way of geting mails from this mailbox over MAPI?"* Do a web search for [`java mapi`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+mapi) to find solutions.

Comment: I have looked online and most projects that tried to add support for MAPI are closed or websites are down.

Comment: But do you *have* to use MAPI? Can't you use IMAP?

Comment: You are not using MAPI, you are using the Outlook Object Model. Do you mean MAPI-over-HTTP protocol that the latest versions of Outlook are using to talk to the Office 365 mailboxes? In that case you might as well use EWS.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, MAPI is only protocol that this mailbox has enabled, with IMAP it would be a lot easier to do.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I see that EWS won't get any new updates and Microsoft suggest using MicrosoftGraph instead. I think this is the way i sould go? I need to find out if i can use it with this mailbox.

Comment: EWS is very much supported, and Outlook itself uses for OOF settings and F/B retreival.